Using Disc Method getting wrong Volume
Find the Volume, using: $$V = \pi \int_{a}^{b} (f(x))^2 dx$$

$$y = \frac{x}{2} + 1$$
The limitation I am able to find from the figure,$\left[1, 5\right]$.
Integral:
$V = \pi \int_{1}^{5} (\frac{x}{2} + 1)^2 \, dx$
$= \pi \int_{1}^{5} \frac{x^2}{4} + 1 \, dx = \pi \left[\frac{x^3}{12} + x\right]_{1}^{5}$
Applying:
$F(5)-F(1) = \frac{85 - 13}{12}$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $$\color{red}{\frac{79\pi}{3}}$$

$(\frac{x}{2} + 1)^2 = \frac{x^2}{4} + x + 1 \neq \frac{x^2}{4} + 1$

@Nic Thanks a lot for seeing the error.

The distributive law applied to a binomial square is
$$
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2,
$$
so with $a = \frac{x}{2}$ and $b = 1$,
$$
\bigl(\tfrac{x}{2} + 1\bigr)^2 
= \bigl(\tfrac{x}{2}\bigr)^2 + 2\bigl(\tfrac{x}{2}\bigr)(1) + (1)^2
= \tfrac{x^2}{4} + x + 1. 
$$

Yes. Nic got it.

I missed it. I am fully aware of this.
